# Running simultaneous operations in Mailcore2

Tags: mailcore2

Is it possible to run multiple operations simultaneously? I'm downloading emails in the background through an operation. When my users open an email to view it I start another operation to get the message - this doesn't run until the downloading operations are complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the property `allowsFolderConcurrentAccessEnabled` if you think you're always be on a server that supports it.
Additionally, when you fetch a message, you can use a `urgent` flag to tell if you need to fetch it as soon as possible. It will make operation run simultaneously.

```
- (MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation *) fetchMessageOperationWithFolder:(NSString *)folder
                                                               uid:(uint32_t)uid
                                                            urgent:(BOOL)urgent;
```