# Mailcore2 concurrent download of message

Tags: ios, swift, mailcore2

```
fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder(path, requestKind: requestKind, numbers: indexSet)
```

From my understanding, the queue of "MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation" are managed by the imapSession.

Is it possible / recommended to have 2 MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation running concurrently to download messages more quickly?

I've read this:
[Running simultaneous operations in Mailcore2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904639/running-simultaneous-operations-in-mailcore2)
but it seems like the question is running simultaneous but different operations concurrently whereas what I want to do is run simultaneous operation of the same kind to speed up the whole process

Comment: "but it seems like the question is running simultaneous but different operations concurrently whereas what I want to do is run simultaneous operation of the same kind to speed up the whole process" Could you explain with more details? I don't understand.

Comment: as far as i understand, the conclusion of the other question is that  a single imapsession can run 1 operation to fetch message headers, and 1 operation to fetch message body concurrently 

in my scenario, I'd like to run 2 operations to fetch message headers concurrently

Comment: If it's from different folders, it just works. If it's from the same folder, you'll end up hitting the connections limit of the server. If you'd really like to do it, just use the C++ synchronous API.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà thank you for the suggestion. :) but i've no idea how to do that for now.. my interim solution is to have multiple imapSessions and run the fetchMessagesOperation. :)